# making scatterplot of one variable, split into 18 categories, in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I cannot imagine that no-one asked the question before, but I have been looking for and wresteling with it the whole day without a satisfying answer.
If my question has been asked before, a link to the thread would be good.

I have a dataset which looks somewhat like this:

```
          R01    R02   R03
family01  10     1002  264
family02  654    0     346
family03  46     2     56
```

but with more families and more columns.

I want to make scatterplots, comparing the values in all of the columns with one-another. (so R01 vs R02, R01 vs R03 etc.)
Is there an easy way of doing this in ggplot? I would like to have all of them in one screen. 
I tried rearanging the data like this:

```
family   value   file
01       10      R01
02       654     R01
03       46      R01
01       1002    R02
02       0       R02
03       2       R02
01       264     R03
02       346     R03
03       56      R03
```

but this arrangement doesn't seem to give me what I need. I thought I could use the facet_wrap if I arranged my data this way, but now I cannot find how to plot the values of one file with those of another.

Comment: If your data set is a data.frame, R's base `plot()` command will arrange that as a series of scatterplots. The equivalent for ggplot is `GGally::ggpairs`. https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/#ggallyggpairs

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the output you're trying to get? This little bit of data probably isn't enough to build whatever it is you want.

Comment: If you want to plot each variable against `R01` you'll want to keep that variable as a separate column when you reshape the dataset.  The column names of your long dataset would be like "R01", "value", "file".  For example, if you used `reshape2::melt()` on your first example dataset for reshaping you'd use code like `reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = "R01")`.

Comment: I want to compare each one to every other one. The `plot()` function is almost what I'm looking for, but because I have 18 different columns, the graphs are very small. If I could tell `plot()` to not output all of the duplicates, that would solve it.